# Update an array using another array based on matched property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays like this

```
 let array1 =   [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'A'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'B'
    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'C'
    }]

let array2 =   [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'x'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'y'
    }]
```

I want to update array 1 with the array 2 object values which are matching based on id values.
Result would be something like this.

```
 [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'x'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'y'
    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'C'
    }]
```

I have written something like this but not working .

```
    array1.forEach(item1 => {
        const itemFromArr2 = array2.find(item2 => item2.id== item1.id);
        if (itemFromArr2) {
           item1= itemFromArr2;
        }
     }
  )
```

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check this one-liner out:

```
array1.map(e => (e.name = array2.find(a => a.id == e.id)?.name || e.name, e));
```

**Explanation**: We are mapping over *array1* and searching for the matching id in *array2*, if it is found (`array2.find(a => a.id == e.id)?.name`), we override the name property (`e.name = ...`), otherwise we keep it as it is (`... || e.name`).

**Small example:**

```js
let array1 = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'A'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'B'
}, {
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'C'
}]

let array2 = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'x'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'y'
}]

const newarray = array1.map(e => (e.name = array2.find(a => a.id == e.id)?.name || e.name, e));
console.log(newarray);
```

**Edit** according to @Roster's comment, if you want to override the whole entry use this line:

```
array1.map(e => (e = array2.find(a => a.id == e.id) || e, e));
```

**Second example**:

```js
let array1 = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'A'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'B'
}, {
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'C'
}]

let array2 = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'x'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'y',
  'otherproperty': 42
}]

const newarray = array1.map(e => (e = array2.find(a => a.id == e.id) || e, e));
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Thanks , But what if i have 4 or 5 fields ? i want to update the object irrespective of properties value check. if id matches then just need to update it with array 2 object

Comment: Awesome Explanation and Answer. But again would like to know last parameter , e) ? What it indicates. Sorry  I am new to js/ ts

Comment: Good code, but I think it can be a little shorter `array1.map((e) => array2.find(({ id }) => id===e.id) ?? e )`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `update` array to a `Map`, then iterate the `target` array with `Array.map()`, and merge it with the object of the same key in the `upateMap` if it exists:

```js
const fn = (predicate, target, update) => {
  const updateMap = new Map(update.map(o => [predicate(o), o]))
  
  return target.map(o => {
    const key = predicate(o)
    
    return updateMap.has(key)
      ? { ...o, ...updateMap.get(key)}
      : o
  })
}

const array1 = [{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"},{"id":3,"name":"C"}]
const array2 = [{"id":1,"name":"x"},{"id":2,"name":"y"}]

const result = fn(o => o.id, array1, array2);
console.log(result);
```

With types ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKgPgBQAcBOApgCYCWwAhlIQFwzYX4Dmd6AlMpjBWAJ4A0MKIyaEorANoBdQQFdcxKrRjppHJFwDeAKBgxQkWPMXUAshVzIYYQgHcY53NmNKAdAFsL2EJxgSCJORK3myCIFJsbLow0URQsviIwsxiHl4%20GjA6enoG0DAA1oS8VgFklNQh0XrVMHEJiC5mFq4AFhQQ2EW8UTk5APxZMK4jIIIjrk2Ejq6iUF3FbAC%20tXp0INFLUSvaebCM%20BS8AIxWEpoARKTEFzTH-BdgFO6EtxcAghdL-JfXtwBMDyeLzeACEvj8rjcaABmIHPV40C4AYS%20Ul24HyByO-zOv2h90eCLeAA8IfiAfCQUjeGjtBjDHVCBBZAAbWAoBDeXwgVzXQTYk4C-CHXj-NgAbgZEBArMIrlZICY2CILPZkqAA)):

```
const fn = <T>(predicate: (arg: T) => any, target: T[], update: T[]) => {
  const updateMap = new Map(update.map(o => [predicate(o), o]))
  
  return target.map(o => {
    const key = predicate(o)
    
    return updateMap.has(key)
      ? { ...o, ...updateMap.get(key)}
      : o
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `hashmap` to update the array.

The reason of `hashmap` is for performance.

```js
const array1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "A" },
    { id: 2, name: "B" },
    { id: 3, name: "C" },
];

const array2 = [
    { id: 1, name: "x" },
    { id: 2, name: "y" },
];

const hashMap2 = array2.reduce((carry, item) => {
    const { id } = item;
    if (!carry[id]) {
        carry[id] = item;
    }
    return carry;
}, {});

const output = array1.map(item => {
    const newName = hashMap2[item.id]?.name;
    if (newName) {
        item.name = newName;
    }
    return item;
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Generics:

```
const array1 =   [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'A'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'B'
    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'C'
    }]

const array2 =   [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'x'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'y'
    }]


function mergeArray<T>(arr1: T[], arr2: T[], identifier: keyof T): T[] {
    for(const oItem of arr2){
        const itemInArr1 = 
            arr1.find(item => item[identifier] === oItem[identifier]);
        if(itemInArr1){
            for(const key in itemInArr1){
                itemInArr1[key] = oItem[key];
            }
        } else {
            arr1.push(oItem);
        }
    }
    return arr1;
}

console.log(mergeArray(array1,array2, 'id'));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngRhgXhjg2gbwFgAoHMmAcgEsATCgLhjQBoTycKw4BbAUwcoBBCmzIBfZjCKl21OowBMrGeU49+jCgCERKmBKmjVtAQGZl7Slz4CKAYV3kxAXRIlQkWImQoFWMgRGZHICLEEc1hqUAB6O4pLSliGKFrKRtihxOC5uxCQAZgCuYMBQVOAwfAgA5ryCSKgAPAAqAHwAFN5ojM24zpLeCj19krS8YGX5VLwIjADWvCgg+TDNAJTDzoZ6+SAI7R7QMCAAklC83Mcrg2uJljCHsFTn3Cdg9QgY2OH3XQB0UzANHazwuWFaMFB3FwYwmVCmMy2mGRxzOFxhNHGk2mCGcawA3D8cPCQS83h80LciexdvtHjAFihIWBIWT3khKXd7vcoeSObhGUjUS8BYtnIS9NyxNSxDBeAAbCC8bbc8j-AAOhQgAAt2qcXgSZUFpXoELwoIUECyuhKTe5wBAQPLeH95SBqu0qrUPqhOg10MxvKglJQTGsCUA)

This iterates over the itmes in `array2`and checks their existence inside `array1` based on the identifier.

Based on whether or not the item exists in `array1`, the item will be modified, or the item from `array2` is pushed into `array1`.